# Git Bash with Ansicon

Tags: git-bash, ansicon

How can I get a clean install of Git Bash and Ansicon to work together, so that I get coloured output when using the Git Bash terminal?

I've tried downloading ansicon, adding the x64 directory to my path and typing

```
ansicon.exe -i
```

into the Git Bash terminal. No output is given from the command, and when I run the cucumber command, I still get the following output:

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher
(https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
```